# What should I use to fill a gap between oak trim and wall?

Tags: trim

I have oak trim on my baseboard. What do you use to fill in the gaps between the trim and the wall? Do I use regular caulk and then paint it the color of the wall?

Comment: Or you can try clear caulk.  Test it in a corner and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are exactly right, I use latex caulk to fill the gaps and then paint when dry.  This will create a seamless appearance.  I've seen homes where the owners have caulked *all* their trim and it looks fantastic -- very clean.

Edit for clarity: I always strike off the bead square (which I make sure gets pushed down into the space) with a sharp cornered putty knife blade.