# How can I fix my window trim after having new windows installed?

Tags: windows, trim, window-frame

I had new windows installed and some of the original trim was roughed up pretty bad in the process. This trim is original to the house so I want to do my best to clean it up. The window in question is in a bathroom without a fan so it can get pretty dewy in there so whatever I do needs to be able to withstand that. I know I’ll need to do some sanding to get rid of some of the splinters and chips but not sure what to fill the gaps with before I repaint. I have some semigloss paint that matches so I already have that on hand. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Or this? [What should I use to fill a gap between oak trim and wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36834/what-should-i-use-to-fill-a-gap-between-oak-trim-and-wall)

Comment: If you or someone you know is a bit artistic, try some automotive body filler.  It sets up pretty quickly, and can be shaped while it's still setting up.  Then sand & paint.

Answer (score 1):

Was that done on a Friday afternoon?
Were they paid to fix the trim as part of the job?

If not, then what you really need to do is strip it all, clean up all the joints, not just that one [sink & fill the lazy pinning while you're at it] & redo from start. It could be lovely with a bit of TLC.

Otherwise, if all you want is cheap & cheerful, use decorator's caulk - covers a multitude of sins. As my friend & professional decorator would say, "A blind man on a galloping horse wouldn't notice it." Neither will you in six weeks [especially as you can already ignore the horizontal joint & the disused {roller blind?} clip].